# Como obter um retorno de um subreport no jasper

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jaspersoft-studio

Olá,
 Tenho uma variável dentro de um subreport e quero passar ela para o mainreport, porém por algum motivo a variável está chegando com valor null no main report. Criei uma variável exmeplo **A** nos dois relatórios pra exemplificar.

---

Declaração da variável no subreport

```
...
    <variable name="A" class="java.lang.String" resetType="None">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA["teste"]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
...
```

Declaração da variável no mainreport

```
...
    <variable name="A" class="java.lang.String" resetType="None">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
...
```

Chamada no mainreport

```
...
            <subreport runToBottom="false">
                <reportElement uuid="5e524426-f04b-47d8-b7cd-2be45f031ebd" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="4" width="391" height="10" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
                <returnValue subreportVariable="A" toVariable="A"/>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "subreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
...
```

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Seria válido vc passar qual a versão você está usando.

Creio que esteja faltando vc definir qual o tipo de retorno da expressão subreport como java.lang.String

Tente:

```
    <subreport runToBottom="false">
        <reportElement uuid="5e524426-f04b-47d8-b7cd-2be45f031ebd" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="4" width="391" height="10" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
        <returnValue subreportVariable="A" toVariable="A"/>
        <subreportExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "subreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
    </subreport>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu faco isto via java, mas segue a mesma logica.

Veja como esta meu JRXML

```
<subreport>
    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="1" y="40" width="553" height="20" uuid="dcb4de43-b64f-4e50-a4b1-5ad31a1cd9a2"/>
    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("carga.ordens.pedidos")]]></dataSourceExpression>
    <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR2}]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

Meu codigo java

```
public static Object printJasper(@NonNull final Collection data,
                                 @NonNull String titulo,
                                 String subReport) throws JRException {

    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("SUBREPORT_DIR",  new ClassPathResource(String.format("/target/classes/jasper/%s.jasper", subReport)));

    JasperPrint print  = JasperFillManager.fillReport(String.valueOf(new ClassPathResource(String.format("/target/classes/jasper/%s.jasper"
            , titulo))),map, buildDatasource(data));

    return exportPdf(print);

}
```

Veja que eu passo somente o caminho do jasper na tag SUBREPORT_DIR